# “The day before” vs. “before the day”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> - They backed out of the deal **the day before** they were due to sign the contract.
> - They backed out of the deal **before the day** they were due to sign the contract.

What is the difference in meaning between these sentences?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"The day before" means exactly one day before. If they were due to sign the contract on Friday, this means they backed out on Thursday.

"Before the day" could be any time before the specified day. They might have backed out Tuesday or Wednesday or weeks before the schedule day.

Comment: "Before the day" also sounds a lot like "any time before daytime".

Comment: To me the second construction sounds a little awkward. If "they" backed out at some unspecified time before the contract was due to be signed, why not just write "They backed out of the deal before they were due to sign the contract."?

Comment: @SpencerWilliams It could mean that by itself, but not as used in the sentence in the question.

Comment: @Deepak That could include backing out on the same day, but at an earlier hour. "before the day" means it was the previous day or earlier.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm aware of this nuance, but to me it seems pointless to try to be precise about the withdrawal being before the actual day, but remaining imprecise about whether it was two days before, a week before, a month before etc. That's what makes it awkward in my view.

Comment: A native speaker would likely use the second form only if the day itself is very significant and there's no other name for it.  For example, "The groom disappeared before the day of the wedding" would make sense.  You could even use it for a contract signing if, for example, there were some requirement to have the contract signed by a particular day, and this caused the deadline to be missed.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, in general I'd be more likely to simply say, "before they were due to sign ..." But I wouldn't find it odd for someone to say "before the day my vacation begins" or "before the day I met my wife". I suppose in some contexts it might be important that it was not just ten minutes before, but at least the previous day. So I'd agree that it is probably an unusual thing to say, but not unheard of.

Comment: +1  @Deepak: *We backed out of that deal (long | not long ) before the day we were supposed to sign the papers.* would be idiomatic; an unqualified **before the day** is unlikely, but grammatical.

Comment: @Deepak "[I]t seems pointless to try to be precise about the withdrawal being before the actual day, but remaining imprecise about [how far before]" Not necessarily. By saying that they withdrew before the actual day, you're saying that they gave at least a little notice. In some contexts, that might be important. (Consider somebody backing out of their wedding at least a day before it was supposed to happen, versus five minutes before.)